# Shopping cart rule: first product 50% off (only first product) - How do I?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

we are trying to set-up the following rule

- 50% discount on your first (any) T-shirt

So when you buy 1 or 2 T-shirts you get 50% discount on the first product only. Can this be done?

I managed setting up the rule as below. This works for 1 SKU. When I add 1 or 2 the discount is always (only) 50% on the first product.

But now when I add another SKU: then the rule is fired all over again. And now the 50% discount is *also* applied to the second SKU

It needs to be applied only to the first (or any first) SKU, then stop ...

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: have u tried using the conditions??

Comment: I have tried all. There is no identifier: first product only. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with default promotions. <strike>The only way to do it in standard Magento is to use a coupon code that can only be used once per customer</strike>.

If you don't want to use a coupon code, you will have to program your own validation (start with `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator`) or write an observer that stores if your rule has already been processed using `Mage::register()`. The event you're looking for is `sales_quote_address_discount_item` and it would be as simple as not calling the `process()` method of the validator if the `Mage::registry()` tells you the rule has already been applied.

Edit:

So this was very educational. I got it working using a combination of an observer and a rewrite.
[image: Result cart]

I didn't integrate it into the promotion rules, as that would be quite a bit more work. Instead, I made a system configuration where you can fill in the names of the rules you want to work only for one order row.
[image: Admin config]

You can download it [here](http://magemana.nl/ports/dist/MageStack_ConsumeOnce-1.0.0.tgz). Doesn't come with support. :)

Comment: How then do it with a coupon?

Comment: Ack, sorry. I totally forgot that coupon usage per customer is also tied to logged in customers. So, if you need this for unregistered users, you can't without writing code (or an extension).

Comment: Per customer is not our issue. Setting it up for first product only ... That's the hard one